# About a compact net in the product space $\ell_{2}\times c$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am reading [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266225051_Measures_of_noncompactness_condensing_operators_and_fixed_points_An_application-oriented_survey) by J. Appell (if you want, you can download for free by looking for the title in Google), but I have some doubts with example 3.1 on p. 174, which I describe below.

Let the product space $X:=\ell_{2}\times c$, where $\ell_{2}$ is the usual space of square summable sequences and $c$ the space of all convergent sequences. Consider in $X$ the the Euclidean norm $\|(x,y)\|^{2}:=\|x\|^{2}+\|y\|^{2}$. I assume that, really, this norm is $\|(x,y)\|^{2}:=\|x\|_{\ell_{2}}^{2}+\|y\|_{c}^{2}$, where $\|\cdot\|_{\ell_{2}}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{c}$ are the usual norms of $\ell_{2}$ and $c$, respectively. Do you agree?

Then, define the linear operator $L:X\longrightarrow X$ by $L(x,y):=(0,x)$. In the cited paper is stated that 
$$
L(B(X))=\{(0,y):y\in B(c)\}:=M,
$$ 
where $B(X)$ and $B(c)$ are the closed unit balls of $X$ and $c$, respectively. I am nor sure that this assert be correct: given any $(0,y)\in M$ with $y:=(y_{n})_{n\geq 1}\in B(c)$ such that $\lim_{n}y_{n}=\varepsilon >0$, Can we find $x\in \ell_{2}$ and $y\in c$ such that $L(x,y)=(0,x)\in M$? (recall that as $x\in\ell_{2}$, $\lim_{n} x_{n}^{2}=0$).

On the other hand, in the cited paper is stated the following:

"...for each $(0,y)\in M$ we can find a finite sequence $\tilde{y}$ such that $\|y-\tilde{y}\|\leq 1/2$, and the subset $\tilde{M}:=\{(0,\tilde{y}):y\in M\}$ is a compact $1/\sqrt{2}$-net for $M$ in $X$."

Why is true the above assert? Can we take such $1/\sqrt{2}$-net in $M$?

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions and comments.

Comment: I suspect that there is some mix up of notations here. With the given definitions it is not true that$L(B(X))=M$

Comment: Sorry!!!!!!! I think that I have deleted an answer or a comment!!

Comment: @user123043 you cannot delete another persons answer or comment. It was deleted by a mod or the user themselves (the scenario: 1. write answer, 2. realise answer is wrong, 3. delete answer $\ $  happens often)

Comment: The statement that $L(B(X))= \{0\}\times B(c)$ is true. Note for example that $\{0\}\times B(c)\subset B(X)$ and then $L(\{0\}\times B(c)) = \{0\}\times B(c)$ so only $L(B(X))\subseteq \{0\}\times B(c)$ is left to be proven. Suppose $(x,y)\in B(X)$ then $1≥\|(x,y)\|^2 = \|x\|^2+\|y\|^2≥ \|y\|^2 = \|L(x,y)\|^2$ and indeed $L(x,y)\subseteq \{0\}\times B(c)$.

Comment: Thanks S. harp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|y\|_c=\sup |y_n|$ for each $y=(y_n)\in c$ then for each $0<\varepsilon<1$ there is no set $K$ of $c$ such that $K$ is a compact $\varepsilon$-net for $B(c)$ is $c$ (or, that is the same, a set $\{(0,y):y\in K\}$ is a compact $\varepsilon$-net for $M$ is $X$). Indeed, suppose to the contrary that there exists such a set $K$. Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $B(c)$ such that $\|y-y'\|_c=2$ for each distinct $y,y'\in A$. For instance, we can put $A=\{a^m:m\in\Bbb N\}$, where for each $m$ the first $m$ coordinates of $a^m$ are $1$, the $m+1$-th coordinate is $-1$, and the remaining coordinates are zeroes. Since $K$ is a $\varepsilon$-net for $B(c)$, for each $a^m$ there exists $y^m\in K$ such that $\|y^m-a^m\|_c\le\varepsilon$. The triangle inequality implies that $\|y^m-y^{m'}\|_c\ge 2(1-\varepsilon)$ for each distinct $m$ and $m'$. This follows that $\{y^m\}$ is a sequence of points of a compact metric space, containing no convergent (even no Cauchy) subsequence, which is impossible.

Comment: Dear Alex Ravsky,

Thanks for your reply, but I do not see it very clear...In the statement

"...for each $(0,y)\in M$ we can find a finite sequence $\tilde{y}$ such that $\|y-\tilde{y}\|\leq 1/2$, and the subset $\tilde{M}:=\{(0,\tilde{y}):\tilde{y}\in \tilde{M}\}$ is a compact 1/$\sqrt{2}$-net for M in X."

From our notation, $M$ is the image, under $L$, of the closed unit ball of $X$. Therefore, I feel that $L(U_{X})\neq \{0\}\times B(c)$ (otherwise, your reply will be correct), but $L(U_{X})\neq \{0\}\subset B(c)$.

Comment: This example is essentially given in the Akhmerov et al book  https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=es&id=3HwECAAAQBAJ&q=2.4.11#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @user123043 $M=L(B(X))=\{0\}×B(c)$, as already [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339855/about-a-compact-net-in-the-product-space-ell-2-times-c/3343876?noredirect=1#comment6874847_3339855) s.harp, and you even said "thanks".

Comment: Again, thanks. So, we can say that there is an errata in the cited paper in the statement of my question.